# Div Clears Float Even Though No Clear Property is Set

Tags: css, css-float

This is way-too-basic question, but the behavior of the div on my website leaves me perplexed.

I've experienced identical issue before, so I am sure I am doing something wrong, consistently, or misunderstanding some fundamental CSS rule.

**Question:** Why does the red div tag near the bottom right of the site clears its left counterpart? There's no "clear" rule applied to it!

Here's the html:

```
<div id="home-left">
<?php 
echo "Some php=generated content";
?>
</div> <!-- END HOME-LEFT -->

<div id="home-right-container">
<p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</div> <!-- END HOME-RIGHT-CONTAINER -->
```

And here's the corresponding CSS:

```
#home-left {
width:280px;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
//clear:both; /* STAY CLEAR OF THE SCROLLER-FEATHER-CONTAINER! */
}

#home-left h3 {

    //font-size: 1.128571429rem;
font-size:12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#home-left p {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    margin: 0 0 1.514285714rem;
font-size:11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#home-right-container {
width:100px;
background:red;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: `//` is not considered as comment in CSS.

Comment: Thank you, @Matyas! I forgot about that. Seems to work in most cases, though. ;-)

Comment: put floated container before `<div id="primary" class="site-content">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left div is actually clearing the right counterpart. This is because if the element is not `floated`, it will basically take on a margin stretching across the entire width of the page.

**Two Solutions:**

1. Add `float: left` to the `div` on the left side of the red box.
2. Add `display: inline-block` to the `div` on the left side of the lower red box.

Comment: Could you please tell me, @Evan – what display: inline-block would accomplish in this case?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov Inline block allows for elements to be displayed `inline` while retaining their block properties - which allows you to set width, height, etc. So, in this case it would allow the `div` on the left to be displayed *inline* with the red `div` on the right

Comment: I understand, @Evan - but why would it be needed in this particular case?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov It's not *needed*, rather, it's just another solution if you don't want to go the `float` route. Just thought I'd post it thinking you or someone else would find it interesting / helpful

Comment: Oh, I see, @Evan, you meant not "use both 1 and 2", but "either 1 @ 2". Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because it comes after the element that is to the right in the document flow.

You can either switch the element order which will give you the result that you want.  Or float the other element to the left also which can also give the result that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Schleis. I understand my former mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

float allows an element to float to the side of elements below it, not element above it.

If you float #home-left left, the right div will be to the right

Answer (score 1):

Just add float: left on style.css Line 235. Hope this Helps.